# login page without postback

Tags: asp.net, jquery-mobile

I have a login page and on click of Sign In button it is redirecting to another .aspx page but  with postback. I want that on click of button postback should not occur. I want to use json. But i dont know how to use it in my page and how to call it.Please tell me how to avoid postback using json.I want to build an application for mobile and using jquery mobile.

```
My code is
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>
    </title>
    <link href="CSS/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <link href="CSS/my.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="Js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="Js/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="Js/my.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<%-- <asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptmngr" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnlData" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>--%>
<div data-role="page" data-theme="d" id="page1">
        <div data-theme="b" data-role="header"> 
            <h3>
            </h3>
            <div style="">
                <img style="width: 100px" src="Images/QuickMove.png" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" style="padding: 15px">

      <div>
                <p>
                    <b>
                        <span style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);" data-mce-
style="background-color: #ffff00;">
                        </span>
                        <span style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color:   
rgb(255, 102, 0);">
                            ​Survey Login
                        </span>
                    </b>

                </p>
            </div>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain" style="width:100%">
            <label  ID="lblLoginMsg" SkinID="snkError" runat="server" 
ForeColor="Maroon" Font-Bold="True"
                    Font-Size="Small"></label>
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                    <label for="textinput2"><span style="font-family: times new 
roman,times; font-size: medium;">
                        <strong>
                            Username
                        </strong>
                    </span>
                    </label>
                    <input name="" id="txtUserName" placeholder="" value="" type="text" 
runat="server"/>
                </fieldset>
            </div>

            <div data-role="fieldcontain" style="width:100%" >
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                    <label for="txtPassword"> <span style="font-family: times new 
roman,times; font-size: medium;">
                        <strong>
                            Password
                        </strong>
                    </span>
                    </label>
                    <input name="" id="txtPassword" placeholder="" value=""   
type="password" runat="server"/>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
             <div data-role="fieldcontain" style="width:100%" >
       <%--   <button type="button"   data-transition="fade" data-theme="b" 
            data-icon="check" data-iconpos="right" id="btnSignIn" value="Sign In"     
runat="server"   onclick="btnSignIn_Click" />--%>
         <button id="btnSignIn" type="button" runat="server"   
onserverclick="btnclick">Sign In</button>
  </div>
<div data-theme="b" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" >
<h4 style="font-size: 10px">

     &copy;QuickMove
</h4>
</div>        
</div>
</div>

</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

[**JSON**](http://www.json.org/) is data presentation used for exchanging data and is not used for communication you need ajax to validate user you can use [**jQuery Ajax**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). This is a nice article to start using **[jquery ajax with asp.net web methods](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)**

Comment: can you give an example how to use it

Comment: I have added link in answer with nice example http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Answer (score 0):

You need to POST one way or another, because sending login credentials in a GET is simply Not Done for various reasons (including security and web standards), and you can't do it entirely client-side either, because then client-side code (which is tainted by definition) will be in charge of making the login decision.

So you do need a POST, but you *can* avoid the page reload using AJAX (which basically means instead of telling the web browser to make a POST request when the user submits a `<form>`, you make the request from javascript and process the result in a callback without leaving the page). jQuery comes with a complete AJAX API, so you don't need to get down to the nitty-gritty of the XmlHttpRequest object and its implementations on different browsers.

As far as JSON is concerned: JSON is a generic data format, and also a subset of JavaScript proper. It is the standard format for AJAX requests, mainly because it is lightweight, built into most current JavaScript implementations (and a reasonably fast implementation is available for older implementations that can transparently take over when needed), and easy to generate and parse.